# Find all isomorphisms between the group of rotations of the square and the group (Z4, +4)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, cyclic-groups

My solution:

$C4$ = {$e,r,r^2,r^3$} where e-identity element and r is rotation by 90°

$Z4$ = {$0,1,2,3$}

$|Z4|=|C4|=4$

We see that both groups are cyclic.

$C4$ is generated by $r$  and $r^3$.

$Z4$ is generated by $1$ and $3$.

We know that cyclic groups of same order are isomorphic.

We know that isomorphism preserves the order of the element.

Order of the elements:

$|e|=1  ------- |0|=1$

$|r|=4  -------|1|=4$

$|r^2|=2  -------|2|=2$

$|r^3|=4  ---- ---|3|= 4$

We see that in both groups there is 1 element with order equal 1, 1 element with order equal 2 and 2 elements with order equal 4.

So we can create 2 mappings:

ψ : C4 -> Z4

$ψ(e)=0$

$ψ(r)=1$

$ψ(r^2)=2$

$ψ(r^3)=3$

ϕ: C4 -> Z4

$ϕ(e)=0$

$ϕ(r)=3$

$ϕ(r^2)=2$

$ϕ(r^3)=1$

Both mappings are of course bijective because they are 1-1 and onto.

Now we have to prove that ψ and ϕ are homomorphisms.

Let's begin with $ϕ$ :

Let $\phi(r^m)=3m$

$\phi(r^mr^n) = \phi(r^{m+n}) = 3(m+n) = 3m + 3n = \phi(r^m) + \phi(r^n)$.

So ϕ is homomorphism and a bijection so ϕ is isomorphic.

Now we do the same with ψ:

Let $\psi(r^a)=a$

$\psi(r^ar^b) = \psi(r^{a+b}) = a + b =\psi(r^a) + \psi(r^b)$.

So $ψ$ is homomorphism and a bijection so $ψ$ is isomorphic.

We have proved that there exist 2 isomorphisms between $Z4$ and $C4$.

Comment: You are nearly there. An isomorphism must map a generator (element of order 4) of one group to a generator of the other. You have exhibited two such isomorphisms and they are the only ones possible, since there are only two elements of order 4 in each group.

Comment: So now should I prove that ϕ and ψ are homomorphisms? For example ϕ (r^a)=3^a for every a, then ϕ (r^a r^b) = ϕ(r^a+b)= 3^a+b, then ϕ (r^a) + ϕ (r^b)= 3^a + 3^b, is it correct? and how to prove that 3^a+b = 3^a + 3^b in mod 4

Comment: It would be very helpful if you learnt how to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset mathematical formulas in your MSE questions. Apart from that you need to be more careful with the notation: you should (probably) be using multiplication notation in $C_4$, but additive notation in $\Bbb{Z}_4$ (and whatever you choose you should be consistent). So in $\Bbb{Z}_4$, you would be interested in $3a+b = 3a+3b$, not $3^a+b = 3^a+3^b$.

Comment: I don't get it in 100% :(  I know that to prove homomorphism I need to show that ϕ (ab)=ϕ (a) + ϕ (b), so for example ϕ (r*e)=ϕ (r) + ϕ (e) and that's of course correct because ϕ (r)= 3 + 0, so ϕ (r)=3 ,and thats how we mapped but why I don't understand   this line:  3a+b=3a+3b not 3a+b=3a+3b

Comment: I was just quoting your comment to highlight the issue with the notation. $3a+b = 3a+3b$ isn't valid in $\Bbb{Z}_4$, but you don't need it to show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Ahh, ok. So could you please post a comment with the missing part of my solution ?  Because right now I have no idea what should I do to make it 100% correct to be honest.

Comment: You have $\phi(r^m) = 3m$ (check that). So that gives you $\phi(r^mr^n) = \phi(r^{m+n}) = 3(m+n) = 3m + 3n = \phi(r^m) + \phi(r^n)$.

Comment: Ok,  I get it. So is there anything unnecessary in my solution? Because I have to make this homework perfect from start till finish :D In few minutes I will implement everything we have talked about and refresh my solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146650/discussion-between-xyz-and-rob-arthan).